# How to connect a Sparkfun LiPoly Charger to an Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino, lipo, lithium-polymer, oled

I was able to upload the [Adafruit SSD 1306 OLED Library](https://learn.adafruit.com/ssd1306-oled-displays-with-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/usage) to an OLED Display using an Arduino Nano.
Now I want to power the Arduino Nano via a [Lipo Battery](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1570?gclid=Cj0KCQiAjfvwBRCkARIsAIqSWlO3w9bvPhT6YSx5xp5o6gA2vSJMQcAkjiq4xtyh_3IAfllB6LOdfEwaAmOwEALw_wcB) but the battery must be rechargeable and I already have a [Sparkfun LiPoly Charger](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/lipo-usb-charger-hookup-guide?_ga=2.260639631.300762718.1579214143-58205509.1579214143). The Sparkfun Lipoly Charger can use the System Out Header to power a 3.3v Arduino Pro.
[image]

Where do I connect the System Out Header on the Sparkfun LiPoly Charger to power the Arduino Nano with a 3.7v LiPo Battery?

Comment: Am I correct in inferring you're concerned that a 3.7V battery is too high a voltage for a device labeled as 3.3V?

Answer (score 1):

Just connect the system out to the Arduino Pro (BATT connector), as shown in your picture.

The Arduino Pro uses 3.3V for the ATmega328 MCU, but the board (the Arduino itself) has an on-board regulator which can accept up to 12V DC.

Check out the [specs on the item at Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10914):

[image]